# photoshop script - Is it possible to get O(1) access to layers?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a photoshop file with 10k layers, iterating through them takes too much time since its a O(n) process. Is there any way to find layers using a O(1) method? What I'm looking for concretely is a fast way to select all layers with specific same name (for example all layers named "layerA"), without iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the layer names are unique, use:

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var myLayerName = "Layer 1";
srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.artLayers.getByName(myLayerName);
```

In the event that there are two or more layers named "Layer 1", the code above will pick the top most layered called "Layer 1".

Comment: they arent unique, there are multiple layers with duplicate names. Does .getByName become slower if there are 10k layers in the file? For example if the specified name is far from the top. What i mean is that terminology like topmost seems to imply there is some iterating occurring and it returns the first it encounters.

Comment: In the old days Photoshop was limited to 99 layers. Adding one more would delete the one on the bottom. Can you look at this problem differently? Do all 10k layers need to be in the file or could it be broken up into say 10 smaller versions? Would writing an index to a text file (once) help??

Comment: I solved it by making an action that slowly adds the layers from the big file into a new file and merging them little by little, thanks